# Node api not returning data to client ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, http

I Have a very basic http server in Node.js. Right now I just want to return some json to a browser doing a /GET request to a specific url. When I go directly to this localhost adress in my browser (chrome) I get the response in the "write"-method. But the ajax request in my backbone client just gets the 200 OK header back but with no response data when I open dev-tools.

Pretty new at Node. Can anyone help me on this?

This is my code. Just to break it down I have changed from json to text/plain and am returning the string "hello".

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.write('hello');
res.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

So found my problem. Since I had my server and app on two different localhost adresses the request was cross domain (CORS). So I fixed it by allowing CORS calls in my server route.

I added to the header part:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  });
```